# Driver for printer Fuji Xerox DocuPrint C3360?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, printing

I can't find any suitable driver for the Fuji Xerox DocuPrint C3360.

[Fuji Xerox's website](http://www.fujixerox.co.jp/download/apeosport/download/c4300series/linux/) does not have any Debian package nor sources, but it has an [RPM package](http://download.fujixerox.co.jp/pub/exe/apeosport/c4300series/fxlinuxprint-1.0.3-1.i386.rpm). Can I somehow use it on Ubuntu?

Here is the content of the RPM:

```
├── etc
│   └── cups
│       ├── mimefx.convs
│       └── mimefx.types
└── usr
    ├── lib
    │   └── cups
    │       └── filter
    │           ├── pdftopdffx
    │           ├── pdftopjlfx
    │           └── pstopdffx
    └── share
        └── cups
            └── model
                └── FujiXerox
                    └── en
                        └── fxlinuxprint.ppd
```

Those directories exist in Ubuntu Natty, so I copied all files to the relevant directories, and rebooted.

Then in Unity's Add Printer dialog, I added the printer's IP adress, it couldn't find a driver so I selected the PPD manually.

Now whenever I try to print, the printer starts making noise, but then the job fails saying "Media tray needs to be filled". I tried with all trays. The trays have abundant paper. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It finally worked! Here is the full procedure:

1. Download the official RPM, it is the big button at the bottom of [this page](http://www.fujixerox.co.jp/download/apeosport/download/c4300series/linux/).
2. Open it with `Archive Manager`.
3. As root, copy all files found in the RPM to their respective directories.
4. Reboot.
5. In Unity's `Add Printer` dialog, select "Network printer" then "LDP", and type the printer's IP address.
6. It looks for a driver but can't find it, so you are presented with a large list of manufacturers.
7. Above this list, click the PPD addition button.
8. Select the `fxlinuxprint.ppd` you have copied into /usr
9. In `Text Editor`, open the Print dialog, in `Page setup` set `Paper source` to `Tray1`, set `Paper size` to `A4`.
10. Press `Print`, it should print the document after a few minutes, even though "Media tray needs to be filled" errors appear.

UPDATE: If you get a message saying `There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'server-error-internal-error'`, then try with the web interface which runs at `http://localhost:631` by default. It worked in my case on Ubuntu 2012.04.

Comment: Why the official RPM link is dead now? :(

Comment: Indeed the link broke after Fuji Xerox incremented the version. I modified my answer, it should work better.

Comment: Does not work with 2012.04 :-( "There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'server-error-internal-error'."

Answer (score 0):

if you got the .rpm file, you can convert it it to .deb by using alien.
quick search resulted [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien) thread that may help

Comment: I don't trust alien too much so I exploded the RPM by myself and copied its files manually. By the way, alien fails saying "fxlinuxprint-1.0.3-1.i386.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system" (I am on 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-fujixerox
```

In Unity's Add Printer dialog, select "Network printer" then "LPD", and type the printer's IP address.
Then select the driver 'FX'.

I did not try printing the test page; but a double-sided PDF just worked!